# How to display success message in Struts?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

we could display errors in Struts by doing actionErrors.add(key, new Actionmessage("string")), addErrors(request, actionErrors); and then outputting it into a JSP page via

I'm wondering, how do I output success messages in Struts? How do you normally/conventionally do it?

Answer (score 11):

On Struts 1 you can use [ActionMessage](http://struts.apache.org/1.1/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionMessage.html) instances to represent a message to be displayed on a JSP

```
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("message1");
messages.add(ActionMessages.GLOBAL_MESSAGE, new ActionMessage("message2");
saveMessages(request, messages); // storing messages as request attributes
```

"message1" and "message2" are keys for you resources property file. Very similar to ActionError handling

Displaying the messages on JSP is similar to action errors, but you must include the property "message"

```
<logic:messagesPresent message="true">
   <html:messages id="message" message="true">
     <bean:write name="message"/><br/>
   </html:messages>
</logic:messagesPresent>
```

In this example the messages were stored as attribute requests. If you want to have control over the attribute name you can specify any attribute name

```
ActionMessages messages = new ActionMessages();
messages.add("appMessage", new ActionMessage("message1");
saveMessages(request, messages); // storing messages as request attributes
```

Now the messages are stored under the request attribute "appMessage". Setting a custom attribute name may be useful if you want to use JSTL tags instead of Struts tags on JSP for example

Additionally you may save action messages on session scope.

```
saveMessages(request.getSession(), messages); // storing messages as request attributes
```

You can use this feature to show sticky messages over user session, such as user full name for example.

Comment: It's to be noted that the last example about saving messages to session requires Struts 1.2.x or newer.

Comment: This is not all correct info. Only the ActionMessages object has a bean stored in the request. The ActionMessage objects do not, you have to access them via a property of the ActionMessages. So using messages.add(appMessage, ...) does NOT add appMessage as a request attribute.. it will not be accessible in the JSP as <bean:write name=appMessage> or the like.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Struts2, you should be able to use addActionMessage instead of addActionError.

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/struts2-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ValidationAwareSupport.html

Your post is missing what you were putting in your JSP, but if you add an action message, you can use the `<s:actionmessage/>` tag to display what you added.

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/actionmessage.html